# How to convert ResponseBody to JSONObject in Retrofit Android

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, httpresponse

I am calling API using Retrofit in Android. and get response from POST method in form of ResponseBody.

As,my API call is as follow-

```
@POST("api/auth/store-login")
fun postLoginDetail(@Body userData: RequestBody):Call<ResponseBody>
```

Now,I want to convert the response of this call to JSONObject so I can use it in my code.

I did this -

```
    retrofitCall.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody?> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody?>, response: Response<ResponseBody?>) {
            Log.e("response","responseNew ${response.body().toString()}")
            val responseBody = JSONObject("{${response.body().toString()}}")
        }
```

but it is not working as Log.e returns -> `responseNew okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@6015676`
and hence it cannot be converted to JSON as `response.body().to()String` is not String or in JSON format.

My actual response in PostMan is like -
{"clients":["client1","client2"],"has_multiple_clients":true}

Comment: try replacing `response.body().toString()` with `response.body?.string()`

Comment: Yes, Its working for me. Thank you !
But I have a question, I have to store response.body?.string() in variable in order to use it in multiple line. If i use it directly as response.body?.string(), only first line get correct response. other lines gives nothing(empty). Why is that?

Comment: If you follow up on docs on the `string()` method, you will notice that: Once you call response.body().string() the information is cleared, which means the second time you call it you will receive nothing.

Comment: You can also see more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37956452/15749574

Comment: Got it, thanks !

Comment: I will post the comments as answers so you can close the question (just FYI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing `response.body().toString()` with `response.body?.string()` but make sure you save the results, 'cause the `.string()` clears the information after being called, making future calls on response.body return no results